# Vue shows empty page

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have a problem. I try to make vue templates, but after bundle i see the empty page.

main.js

```
'use strict';
import Vue from 'vue'
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    created: function () {
        console.log('root instance was created')
    },
    components: {App},
    methods: {}
});
```

bus.js

```
    'use strict';

import Vue from 'vue';

const bus = new Vue();

export default bus;
```

main.js (bootstrap was commented, because there was an error "can't find module". It can be maybe the main problem... I don't know :( )

```
'use strict';
import Vue from 'vue'
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    created: function () {
        console.log('root instance was created')
    },
    components: {App},
    methods: {}
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>VueJS NodeJS and Express  Todo App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
    <app></app>
</div>
<script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just created a repo for you now - https://github.com/syed-haroon/vue-cli3-starter-template, let me know if you have any issue running it. Initial VueCLI3 and bootstrap4 Setup done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create component:

```
Vue.component('app', {
  template: '<h3>Template Text</h3>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    created: function () {
        console.log('root instance was created')
    },
    methods: {}
});
```

in html:

```
 <div id = "example">
        <app></app>
    </div>
```